# Why array_key_exists() on array of array doesn't work properly?

Tags: php

I've an array of array in php. Both arrays are non indexed (they use keys).

```
 $this->confArr["$sectionName"] = Array(); // case 1
```

This returns true:

```
 isset($this->confArr["$sectionName"]);
```

Because an element with name $sectionName was already set.

```
 $this->confArr["$sectionName"]["$itemKey"] = $itemValue; //case 2
```

I cannot figure out why but this returns always FALSE

```
 array_key_exists($itemKey, $this->confArr["$sectionName"]);
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: Are `$sectionName` and `$itemKey` are actually set?

Comment: If `$itemValue` is `null` (or if you have not given it a value) then `isset` would return `false`. Is it?

Comment: print confArr["$sectionName"]["$itemKey"]; before judging

Comment: `isset()` checks if the value is set and not null. what does `$itemValue` return

Comment: yes of course $sectionName and $itemKey are always set. The same happens with array_key_exists() not only with isset

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro: Most likely you are mistaken in at least one of these assertions. If everything were like that you 'd get `true`. While it is possible that `isset` has a bug and you were the first person to discover it, it is highly unlikely.

Comment: its work well for me, have you tried to `echo var_dump($this->confArr);` ? what did you get?

Comment: What is the reason for wrapping the variables in double quotes? as far as im concerned that is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this:

```
array_key_exists($itemKey, $this->confArr["$sectionName"]);
```

Should be:

```
array_key_exists("$itemKey", $this->confArr["$sectionName"]);
```

Don't know exactly why but it works this way ?

Comment: PHP doesn't even differentiate between numeric string and integer keys... Casting that key implicitly to a string can't make a difference _unless_ there's something we don't know, like $itemKey holds something like a SimpleXML object that responds to `__toString()`.

Comment: I just tested it with PHP 5.3.15, and `$itemKey=42`.  Both return 1.  You need to tell us what `$itemKey` holds.

Comment: That... would probably mean `$itemkey` is not a scalar, but has some method to be converted into one (`__toString()` et al.)? For us wondering, care to show what `var_dump($itemKey);` yields?